# battery status on ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED

Tags: android, battery

I'm just wondering if is there any possibility to obtain battery status in broadcast receiver class that fires on ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED? Documentation suggest not, but it is always worth to ask :)

Cheers
Ray

Answer (score 1):

Call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`. The `Intent` that is returned is the last-broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast, which has your battery status in its extras (see `BatteryManager` for the keys).

If you determine that you are calling it too soon, that `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` is invoked before `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` gets updated, perhaps use `AlarmManager` to schedule yourself to wake up again in a few seconds, and check again then.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I tried this already but I got an error message that I cannot register broadcast from other broadcastReceiver. I found in reference that broadcastReceiver may register other receiver only when the former is not declared in manifest file. This forces me to rethink the program... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Ray: Sorry, call `context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`, where `context` is the Context that was passed into `onReceive()`. For more: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/12/real-use-getapplicationcontext.html

Comment: Why is it when you register this receiver that you get 8-10 notifications of battery changed?