# Reliable way to track Android battery charging/discharging state

Tags: android, android-intent, status, battery

Like many others, I am trying to create a simple app that logs an entry every time the phone is connected or disconnected from the charger. I plan to use this data to calculate average charge and discharge rate over several weeks/months to get an idea of how well the battery is performing over time.

I have got Intent filters declared in the manifest for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`, and they seem to be firing fine.

Now when they are fired, I am registering to receive `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` to get the battery `EXTRA_LEVEL`, `EXTRA_STATUS` and `EXTRA_PLUGGED`. (Reference - [Obtaining usb cable plugged IN/OUT event using EXTRA_PLUGGED does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217789/obtaining-usb-cable-plugged-in-out-event-using-extra-plugged-does-not-work))

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentPowerConn) {
        Intent intentBatChange = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int chargeStatus    = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        int chargeType      = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        int chargeLevel     = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

        Toast.makeText(context, chargeStatus + " " + chargeType + " " + chargeLevel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

However, the `EXTRA_STATUS` that is returned by this sticky broadcast still shows as Discharging when fired immediately after the phone is connected. Other extras like `EXTRA_PLUGGED` and `EXTRA_LEVEL` return correct values though.

A manual refresh to get the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` action after connecting returns the `STATUS` as Charging just fine.

It can't be that the intent received immediately after connecting is stale, since the `EXTRA_PLUGGED` returns the correct type (AC or USB).

I have a workaround where I use the `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED/ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` intent action to determine the charge state (as described here - [How to detect power connected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267161/how-to-detect-power-connected-state)).

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intentPowerConn) {
        Intent intentBatChange = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int chargeStatus    = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        int chargeType      = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        int chargeLevel     = intentBatChange.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

        String action = intentPowerConn.getAction();
        boolean chargeFlag = false;

        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            chargeFlag = true;
        }
        else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            chargeFlag = false;
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, chargeStatus + " " + chargeType + " " + chargeLevel + " " + chargeFlag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I might need to make use of `STATUS` for other scenarios like `BATTERY_STATUS_FULL`, `BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING` and `BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN`.

So I don't want to rely on the Intent.`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` action.

Given this, **what is a reliable way to detect the current charge state?**

I was considering adding a 2 sec delay before I register the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent;` though I haven't tested this out yet, I figure it might work.